# Artifactory won't start - [ERROR] Failed to execute query: Table 'unique_ids' already exists

Tags: mysql, artifactory

I keep getting this error when I try to start Artifactory: `[art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.u.CommonDbUtils :57) - Failed to execute query: Table 'unique_ids' already exists:`. I have tried renaming that table in mysql, however Artifactory then ran into another duplicate table:`[art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.u.CommonDbUtils :57) - Failed to execute query: Table 'binaries' already exists:`

When I tried restarting Artifactory after that it ran into the initial duplicate problem with the 'unique_ids' table, so it seems the solution is not to rename these duplicate tables as they are being created on start and Artifactory will continue to run into these duplicate errors every time it starts again after creating them.

Does anyone know why Artifactory keeps running into this problem and how I can make it stop?

Comment: I'm just going to grab this out of thin air since I have no clue about Artifactory, but it seems like it is responsible for creating those tables that it keeps conflicting with. Perhaps because it never finished the first time start up it tries to create said tables every time. Have you tried cleaning the database and starting fresh?

Comment: Thank you, I think that was exactly the problem.

Comment: Awesome, I'll create an answer :)

Comment: dont forget to accept an answer if it helped you out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artifactory uses specific tables that it creates for itself (as part of its startup process). Perhaps something went wrong during said process and now it keeps trying to create the tables that it needs while they already exist. Wiping your database and restarting Artifactory should resolve the issue.